# How to get date_diff from previous rows in Presto?

Tags: sql, presto

I'm trying to get a `diff_date` from Presto from this data.

```
timespent | 2016-04-09T00:09:07.232Z | 1000          | general
timespent | 2016-04-09T00:09:17.217Z | 10000         | general
timespent | 2016-04-09T00:13:27.123Z | 250000        | general
timespent | 2016-04-09T00:44:21.166Z | 1144020654000 | general
```

This is my query

```
select _t, date_diff('second', from_iso8601_timestamp(_ts), SELECT from_iso8601_timestamp(f._ts) from logs f 
              where f._t = 'timespent'
               and f.dt = '2016-04-09'
               and f.uid = 'd2de01a1-8f78-49ce-a065-276c0c24661b'
               order by _ts)
from logs d
where _t = 'timespent'
and dt = '2016-04-09'
and uid = 'd2de01a1-8f78-49ce-a065-276c0c24661b'
order by _ts;
```

This is the error I get

```
Query 20160411_150853_00318_fmb4r failed: line 1:61: no viable alternative at input 'SELECT'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you want [`lag()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#lag):

```
select _t,
       date_diff('second', from_iso8601_timestamp(_ts),
                 lag(from_iso8601_timestamp(f._ts)) over (partition by uid order by dt)
                )
from logs d
where _t = 'timespent' and dt = '2016-04-09' and
      uid = 'd2de01a1-8f78-49ce-a065-276c0c24661b'
order by _ts;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select date_diff('Day',from_iso8601_date(substr(od.order_date,1,10)),CURRENT_DATE) AS "diff_Days"
from order od;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select date_diff('minute',timestamp '2010-05-22 16:00:00+0000', timestamp '2018-05-22 16:05:00+0000');
```